# ffmpeg video generation process optimization

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am generating video using ffmpeg by combining images, audio, logo and some text sliding from right to left. Currently I am using four different ffmpeg commands to complete my video generation process.

Command 1: Below command combines the images and output a video with desired animation

```
ffmpeg \
-t 5 -i 1.jpg \
-t 5 -i 2.jpg \
-t 5 -i 3.jpg \
-t 5 -i 4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -s "800x450" ./out_fade.mp4
```

Command number 2: Then I use this 2nd command to add audio to my video.

```
ffmpeg -i 'input_video.mp4' -i 'audio.mp3' -codec copy -shortest video_out.mp4
```

Command number 3: This is used to add logo to my video on top left location.

```
ffmpeg -i 'input_video.mp4' -i 'logo.png' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy 'video_out.mp4'
```

Command number 4: This is used to add the sliding text in a red box at the bottom of the video screen.

```
ffmpeg -i video_input.mp4 -vf "drawbox=y=ih-80:color=#ef2626@0.8:width=iw:height=80:t=fill,drawtext=text='This is a testing text example.':expansion=normal:y=h-line_h-20:x='if(eq(t\,0)\,w\,if(lt(x\,(0-tw))\,w\,x-4))':fontfile='Lora/Lora-Regular.ttf':fontcolor=white: fontsize=40" video_final.mp4
```

This process is slow I think and I am thinking is it possible I can combine these 4 processes into one or at least reduce it to two commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the combined command,

```
ffmpeg \
-i 1.jpg \
-i 2.jpg \
-i 3.jpg \
-i 4.jpg \
-i 'audio.mp3' \
-i 'logo.png' \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p,scale=800:450,setsar=1[v]; \
 [v][5]overlay=25:25,drawbox=y=ih-80:color=#ef2626@0.8:width=iw:height=80:t=fill,drawtext=text='This is a testing text example.':expansion=normal:y=h-line_h-20:x='if(eq(t\,0)\,w\,if(lt(x\,(0-tw))\,w\,x-4))':fontfile='Lora/Lora-Regular.ttf':fontcolor=white: fontsize=40" \
-c:a copy -shortest ./out_fade.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm.